# RDP Issue! Prompting for username and password

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

We recently upgraded a PC from Windows 7 to Windows 10 (1909 18363.815).  Internally if we RDP to the machine, we enter our domain username and password. We are then brought to the PC and once again prompted for a password.  If it’s a new user to that PC, the user will have to select “Other User” and then enter their username and password again.  We’ve tried everything here:
https://www.kapilarya.com/fix-need-to-sign-in-twice-on-windows-10-fall-creators-update
and here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/troubleshoot/cannot-authenticate-or-must-authenticate-twice
and here:

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/92824-enable-always-prompt-password-upon-remote-desktop-connection.html#option1
Nothing seems to fix the issue.  Its only happening on 2 out of 50 PC’s.

Comment: If the said PC is part of a domain. Check the connection to the domain. You can refer to this link=https://answers.uillinois.edu/47575

Comment: Connection to the domain is fine.

Comment: The issue was solved, by removing the old software named "2x RDP Client".